# i want to split content of text into pages wise in php

Tags: php, html

```
while ($data3 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2)) {
    ?>
        
    <section class="page">
        <div class="front">
            <?php 
     
     echo "<h2>Page " . ($i + 1) . "</h2>";
     echo "<p>$data3['des']</p>";
     ?>

        </div>
        <div class="back">
            dddd
        </div>
    </section>

    <?php

}
```

Here $data['contain'] the paragraphs. we want to split each loops paragraph into pages each pages contain one or two paragraph. front class contain some paragraph. and back class contain other paragraph. How can i do it.

actually i want to create eBook using php. front class contain data. and back class contain back page data

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output. As it stands, your description is not clear enough for anyone to implement anything.  See also [ask]